# Exception while calling java method from cpp using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I am getting the following error while trying to call a function in java from cpp class to save a boolean in memmory. I am using a class called MyAdapter.cpp to call function to MyAdapterJni.cpp. I have following function written in MyAdapterJni.cpp

```
bool GetBooleanJni(const char *key, bool defaultValue)
{
     cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
    jboolean ret = false;
    if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "GetBoolean", "(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z"))
    {
        return ret;
    }
    ret = methodInfo.env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, defaultValue);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);

    return ret;
}
```

and i have following function in myManager.java class

```
public static boolean GetBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue)
{
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
}
```

i get the following log on my logcat

> 12-14 12:06:32.024: W/dalvikvm(9575): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lcom/mygames/Game/MyManager;
>
> 12-14 12:06:32.024: D/libMyManager(9575): Failed to find static method id of GetBoolean

My java class is inside package com.mygames.Game

Can anyone please tell me what can possibly cause this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of `MyManager` throws a `NullPointerException`, which probably prevents determining the method id, so you might want to look at that. Note that not only the class initializer could throw this but also initialization of any static fields. You could put all initialization into the class initializer and then debug from there, something there must be `null`.

Comment: @Glinda The NullPointerException comes from the Java side. My guess is, before the methodId is received, internally the java class initializer and static field initializers are run, and one of them throws the error.

Comment: How do i figure what exactly throws the error from java class

Comment: @Glinda You could put all initialization in the class initializer and check what is wrong, i.e. check all variables for null before you use them, catch exceptions and print the stacktrace, or attach your java debugger to the process (not sure how to do that though).

Comment: Thank you.. The problem was with class initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the instance of the activity in which you running this (say cocos2dxActivity) and do the implementation in runonUiThread....

```
public static boolean GetBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
Cocos2dxActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                 return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);   
        }
    });

    }
}
```

**Note:** It might give you some error of making function parameters. Hope you understood if not please feel free to ask ...

Answer (score 0):

i was also having this issue, and in my case, running my java method functionality on main UI thread solved my problem. e.g. inside your java method

```
Activity ac=(Activity) context;
     ac.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
     {
         public void run() 
            {
                 //your code here
            }
     });
```